# Python multilingual localization

Tags: python, localization, gettext

I am working a backend project written in python to provider multilingual strings to my frontend handset. Some how I got some text translation that will change the position. I want to know how to do that?
Example:
Cathy invited Thomas.
translated to
Thomas 被 Cathy 邀請了.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict interpolation instead.

```
_('%(inviter)s invited %(invitee)s.') % {'inviter': 'Cathy', 'invitee': 'Thomas'}
             ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
 u'%(invitee)s 被 %(inviter)s 邀請了.'
```

Comment: Can you please add an import statement to make it clear what the underscore is for? Or is this something that depends on the implementation? Some clarity of the underscore would be helpful.

Comment: @thedawnrider: It's [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html) stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use paramterised string interpolation

```
params = {"inviter": "Cathy", "invitee": "Thomas"}
eng_str = "%(inviter)s invited %(invitee)s" % params
trans_str = "%(invitee)s 被 %(inviter)s 邀請了." % params
```